# Bootstrap 3 collapse menu not collapsing

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Could someone take a look at my site and tell me why my menu doesn't collapse after selecting a link.  I've been searching online and most answers point to getting the latest version of bootstrap or jQuery, however I'm using jQuery v2.1.3 and bootstrap v3.3.1 which I think are the most recent versions.

http://brianfout-001-site1.smarterasp.net/adventureworks/#home

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't posted any code. But try using `.collapse.('hide')`; on the element you want to collapse. By default, the menu won't collapse. You'll need to add this to make it collapse after clicking on the link.

Eg. `$(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');` where the `.navbar-collapse` is the element.

Comment: Thanks.  That worked.  I was under the impression that the navbar was supposed to collapse automatically after selecting a link.